# Import selected functions and classes in python

Tags: python, function, import

How should I import selected functions and classes from script using only 'import script'?

```
#script.py
def func_a():
    return 1

def func_b():
    return 1

def func_c():
    return 1

def func_d():
    return 1


class ClsA(object):
    def func(self):
        return 10
    

class ClsB(object):
    def func(self):
        return 30
```

When I use 'import script' in another script or Jupyter notebook, I'd like to import only functions func_a and func_b, class ClsA. Is it possible to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `from script import func_a, func_b, ClsA` like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from script import func_a, ClsA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import all functions and classes like this

```
from script import *
```

To import specific classes and functions

```
from script import func_a, ClsA, func_b
```